# Geometric meaning of Koszul (co)homology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, soft-question, modules, homology-cohomology

Let $R$ be a ring, associative and unital, and let $A$ be a left $R$-module. Let $x\in A$ and define the complex $K(x)$ to be the complex $0\to R\to R\to 0$ where the middle map is multiplication by $x.$ The homology of $K(x)\otimes A$ are the **Koszul homology modules** $H_q(x,A)$ and the cohomology of the complex $\mathrm{Hom}(K(x),A)$ are the **Koszul cohomology modules** $H^q(x,A).$ For $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ we define $K(\mathbf{x})$ to be the total complex of the tensor product $K(x_1)\otimes\cdots\otimes K(x_n)$ and then define $H_q(\mathbf{x},A)$ and $H^q(\mathbf{x},A)$ similarly.

We also define the **local cohomology** (of $A$ at $\mathbf x$? I am not sure of the terminology here) to be the direct limit $$H^q_\mathbf x(A)=\varinjlim H^q(\mathbf x^i, A).$$

My question is this: **what, if any, is the geometric meaning behind these modules**? The general theory is all well and good, but I feel that when I'm done studying these things they will just slip out of my mind because I have nothing to connect them to. It looks sort of like localization to me, kind of like how the localization of a ring $R$ at an element $x\in R$ is the direct limit of the system $R\to R\to R\to\cdots $ where each map is multiplication by $x.$ I don't have much experience in algebraic geometry however (especially from the scheme-theoretic point of view) so I can't put this into words myself.

Comment: Local cohomology is a purely geometric thing I believe, it’s just the derived functors of the the “sections supported in Z” functor for sheaves on a space X, Z a closed subset of X. We get the module version (for Noetherian R) by applying this to the affine scheme Spec(R), closed subset the vanishing of an ideal. It would be interesting to know if Koszul cohomology has a geometric analogue too, or if it’s genuinely a scheme theoretic thing.